# Fixed height of left post

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a new website, but it still prototype. I'm little confused with fix height of div. I can't explain how apparently. You can visit my website [Here](http://livebeta.alphabetas.co.cc/media.php?modul=thread)

I've used `min-height:100%`. But if left-post `min-height:100%`, and right-post `min-height:100%` it will be if right-post have a little content, the left-post will be more tall than right-post. I want `min-height` (left-post) = `height` (right-post)

However I want to left post (image, name, admin, user id, etc), to be same height with right post (the real post). I've tried it, but I use JavaScript to do that. Please Help me. Sorry if my English is bad, I'm Indonesia, and I not pretty enough in English :)

Comment: It is better if you put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: One thing you could do is give `.post-content` the same background color as the left post, making it look like the left post reaches the bottom.

Comment: I recommend you to make a basic HTML-CSS layout and show us a live page at http://jsfiddle.net/ for us to work on

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `padding-bottom:50px;`.